# Google Scripts: Library doesn't work unless explicily shared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There's a certain type of Google script hat I need to run on several Google spreadsheets that our company utilizes. The only thing that needs changing per spreadsheet is the range that script needs to manipulate.

To avoid having to copy-paste the code from spreadsheet to spreadsheet, I decided to make a library, and link each spreadsheet to that library (by adding the script key in each spreadsheet's script editor).

The main library function simply takes the sheet name of every spreadsheet, and the range to apply the code to.

This is all done from my account, which is also the owner of those spreadsheets.

The spreadsheets themselves are shared with several people, and that number might grow quite a bit in the future. Different emails will be granted access to different spreadsheets.

Today, an account with **editing rights for one of the sheets** that utilizes the library reported that the spreadsheet wasn't functioning properly. I entered the spreadsheet script editor, and upon trying to run the script manually from that account to debug, I got an error message along the lines of "you don't have access to the library".

After following advice given in a Google Products forum, I granted this account view-only rights to the library. The script then worked fine.

However, this is not a good solution: People with edit access to any spreadsheet utilizing the library can invite other people to edit the spreadsheet. Obviously, new invitees won't have read-only rights of the library, so the script will fail for them. Adding those people one by one to the library one by one will be very laborious.

How can I make library work for any user, even if they don't have access to the library, but do have access to the spreadsheet utilizing he library? I can't expose my code publicly, but I don't mind exposing it to people in my company.

Answer (score 3):

You can try deploy your library as [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/overview), which can be *enabled* once in document, and all users will have access to it: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#states

Comment: Can add-ons be "private"? or do they have to be published to the store? Will each user have to "authorize" the add on?

Comment: Yes, it can be published as "private", see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#complete_application_and_publish_your_add-on

Comment: this is looking good, thank you. So if we don't have a G-suite this will still work as long as I install the add-on myself? Do I need to have a G-suite myself?

Comment: You can use regular Google account

Comment: Can you see my “solution” below and maybe suggest an explanation as to why it works?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I *seem* to have found a solution, but I'm not marking it as the correct one yet because it seems so weird to me that this would solve the issue.

A trigger suffices. But only if I add it as my *own* trigger. The script is always called when the spreadsheet is edited: if I add an on edit trigger from "All Your Triggers" menu, which displays all triggers for a user from all scripts, then the code gets run. If however I add it from the "project triggers" menu, the code doesn't run. This looks like a bug.

For clarification:

1. this works without granting *any* user even a read-only access to the library, and as long as the library is added from the libraries menu to the spreadsheet's script editor.
2. This works for spreadsheets not owned by the library owner.
3. Non library owners (with sheet editing rights) still get the error that they have non access to the library if they try to invoke a library function manually from the script editor.

Comment: Look at this triggers restrictions https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions if your edit trigger function doesn't need any authorization, it will run successfully for any user editing spreadsheet.

Comment: @Kos: Thanks for taking the time to help. The only thing puzzling me with this "solution" is why the trigger fires fine when added from "All Your Triggers" dialog, but won't run when added from "this project's triggers" menu. It's perfectly fine by me, as it doesn't expose my library at all. Just confusing and unexpected.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working in your case, just tested sample trigger, works in both situations for me.